# No enviar Formulario al presionar boton submit

Tags: javascript, html

Estimados,

Estoy realizando un formulario normal con nombre, rut y apellido.

El envío del formulario lo estoy haciendo con un botón, pero cuando los datos no son validados el formulario igual es enviado. entonces mi pregunta es.

> ¿Existe alguna función javaScript que frene el submit del botón al
>   fallar la validación?.

```js
function sendForm(){
    alert("ENTRO SEND");
    alert("valido: "+valido);
     if(valido){
     alert("valido TRUE");
     validateSetDataAhorro();
    }else{
     alert("valido FALSE");
     return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="http://algunsitio.com/prog/usuarionuevo" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
          <input type="text" id="nombre"><br/>
    <label for="apellido">Apellido: </label>
          <INPUT type="text" id="apellido"><br/>
    <label for="email">Rut: </label>
          <INPUT type="text" id="email"><br/>
    <button onclick="javascript:sendForm();" class="btn btn-second"          
      title="Continuar">Boton</button>
  </p>
 </form>
```

Comment: Hola, podrias facilitarnos tu codigo?

Comment: Si que existe, cuando haces el evento on click del boton haces las comprobaciones y si alguna falla lanzas un return para que pare la ejecucion

Comment: aunque sea `return false` igual recarga la página @G3l0

Comment: usa preventDefault, tal que algo asi: `$("#guardar").on("click",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();` esto es jquery pero tambien puedes con JS(al final es lo mismo)

Comment: cual es la sintaxists en JS? porque intenté probar con jquery y no me ha resultado @G3l0

Comment: `document.getElementById("idTuBoton").onclick(function(e){e.preventDefault();});` prueba así

Comment: probé la forma de hacerlo pero me da un error de Js que dice **too much recursion** @G3l0

Comment: O.O, ni idea, ya lo siento, prueba con la solución que te han dejado abajo

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ahora tengo mas noción de como probar. Te pasaste !!! @G3l0

Comment: @fwBasic leí la pregunta y la verdad es que la respuesta que necesitaba no estaba explicada en el otro lado. Gracias por considerarlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si dejas el botón fuera del formulario no lo enviara, entonces validas los campos ( yo no he hecho ninguna validacion), si la variable `valido` es correcta enviara el formulario con `submit()` de javascript en caso contrario muestra una alerta para que valides los campos. Prueba cambiando la variable de `false` a `true` para ver como te funciona.

```js
function sendForm() {
  var valido = false; //DEBERIAS REALIZAR LAS VALIDACIONES
  alert("ENTRO SEND");
  alert("valido: " + valido);
  if (valido) {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  } else {
    alert("VALIDA LOS CAMPOS");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="pagina.php" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre"><br/>
    <label for="apellido">Apellido: </label>
    <INPUT type="text" id="apellido"><br/>
    <label for="email">Rut: </label>
    <INPUT type="text" id="email"><br/>

  </p>
</form>
<button onclick="javascript:sendForm();" class="btn btn-second" title="Continuar">Boton</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta probé dejando el botón fuera del formulario y controlé el envío solo con el js. Funcionó correctamente. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La lógica que estas manejando esta bien. Tienes un boton submit y en el evento click

```
<button onclick="javascript:sendForm();" class="btn btn-second"          
      title="Continuar">Boton</button>
```

LLamas la funcion sendForm().

El problema es que la variable valido no esta definida, cómo sabes que el formulario es válido?. Puede ser que sólo que tenga valores ( si es así lo puedes validar con required en el input).

Debes trabajar la variable valido, que vas a validar y de esa forma solo estarías enviando el formulario cuando se han validado en cliente los datos del formulario.

Una forma básica de validar si los input tienen valor es

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="txtNombre" required>
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

En este código el browser valida que el campo input tenga valor, si es así procede a enviarlo, de lo contrario lo solicita.

Saludos,

Comment: Como no muestra como quiere validar tampoco podemos saber si required es adecuado, si por ejemplo valida que el nombre no contenga numero y hace algun tipo de validación mas compleja ( no lo creo, pero como no se muestra...) required no seria valido

Answer (score 0):

No veo ningún botón de submit, por lo que no te hace falta nada para cancelar.

Realmente tienes un botón normal que hace una llamada javascript. En caso correcto, dicho javascript tendrá que hacer el submit del form, o bien una llamada Ajax o lo que corresponda.